# editing any file in vim shows excalamtion mark

Tags: vim

I am working on a project for a long time. I pushed it to **GitHub** yesterday.

Today when I am trying to edit files with `neovim` or `vim`, it shows an exclamation mark on the left side of the line number **if I edit any lines**. I have edited lines 13 and 17. You can see the exclamation marks on the picture below.

It's really irritating me. Is there any way to remove these exclamation marks? It did not happen before I pushed it to Git. I think this has something to do with Git.

[image]

Comment: You apparently have some Vim plugin installed which marks lines which have changed compared to the latest committed version. You should know better which plugins you are using than we do.

Comment: Do the exclamation marks disappear if you save the file?

Comment: No, the exclamation remains as it is even after saving the file

Comment: This is link to my new `vimrc` file. https://github.com/ajinzrathod/vim/blob/master/vimrc-1.2.vim

Comment: Well the usual troubleshooting advice, which also applies here, is to disable any plugins or custom settings one by one until the problem goes away, to find out what was causing it.

Comment: Ok. Let me try this. I will update if I find any plugins that do this.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218612/discussion-between-ajinzrathod-and-mkrieger1).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the result of the `vim-signify` plugin (https://github.com/mhinz/vim-signify). Just remove line 124 and run `:PlugClean`.

EDIT: line 124 refers to the OP's `~/.vimrc` file. It reads `Plug 'mhinz/vim-signify'` and indicates to the `vim-plug` plugin manager to install `vim-signify`.

Comment: Which line is 124?

Comment: @PatrickCollins Check this vimrc https://github.com/ajinzrathod/vim/blob/master/vimrc-1.2.vim

Comment: @PatrickCollins Good point -- hopefully made it clearer in the answer.